# What are the necessary conditions for a current to be steady?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, magnetostatics

Does the divergence of the volume current density have to be zero for the current to be steady? If so, what are other other conditions? If not, what are the conditions for a steady current in general?

Comment: This is commonly treated in most, if not all, books in electromagnetism. Could you be more precise on what you do not understand about the definition of steady currents? Remember that to ask a question in this site, it is expected that you have first searched on other sources

Comment: Isn't ${\partial j \over \partial t} = 0$ the definition of a steady current?

Comment: I'm reading Griffiths and he defined it as the current that's always there without change and without charge piling up anywhere, so I was first thinking that a constant current implies this, yet there are cases in which the volume current is constant but the volume current density is not, so that caused my confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the divergence of the current density has to be zero for steady current, by definition. The following are all necessary and sufficient conditions for steady current:

1. $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$ (definition)

   The current density has no "sink" or "source". Charges don't pile up anywhere.
2. $\partial \rho(\mathbf{x},t)/\partial t = 0$

   Follows from 1. and the continuity equation $\partial \rho(\mathbf{x},t)/\partial t = -\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t) $. Intuitively, this also confirms the "charges not piling up" premise. The amount of charge in any volume element of the material is constant, and doesn't increase or decrease at any point in time.
3. $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$

   Follows from 2. and Gauss' law $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t) = \rho(\mathbf{x},t)/\epsilon_0$.

*For ohmic materials*, where $\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t) = \sigma \mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t)$, we also have the additional conditions:

4. $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$

   Since $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x},t) = \boldsymbol{\nabla}\cdot\mathbf{J}(\mathbf{x},t)/\sigma  = 0$.
5. $\rho(\mathbf{x},t) = 0$

   Follows from 4. and Gauss' law. So for ohmic materials, the charge density has to be zero everywhere, at all times, for the current to be stationary.